# How to draw a frustum in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to draw a frustrum in rviz that represents the pose of the kinect and its pointcloud. Is this function already available. If not can someone point me towards the tutorials that gives an idea about drawing this.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12875/how-to-draw-a-frustum-in-rviz/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A [Visualization Marker](http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) can probably do what you want, though it may be a bit complicated. [Triangle List](http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Triangle_List_.28TRIANGLE_LIST.3D11.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D) is probably a good place to start.

If you simply want to visualize the pose of the kinect, just add a TF display to rivz

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2022-11-29**:
Is it possible to use Visualization Marker with Triangle List in a python ROS node?